# c - freeing dynamically allocated memory for a variable that is rerturned from a function

Tags: c, memory, heap-memory, free

I've written a function below which formats a string. It removes spaces and the char '-'. It then inserts a space after every 3 characters. I `malloc()` two strings in the function but I only `free()` one of them before I exit the function. I presume this is an example of memory leaking. Is there a way to better design this function so as to not leak memory like this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char* FormatString(char* s) {

    /*Get string length*/
    int original_str_length = strlen(s);
    int num_elements_to_delete = 0;
    int i=0;
    int j=0;

    /*count chars '-' and ' ' to delete*/
    for (int i=0; i <= original_str_length; i++) {

        if((s[i] == '-') || (s[i] == ' ')) {
            num_elements_to_delete++;
        }
    }

    /*allocate new string to hold string minus '-' and ' '*/
    char* string_minus_chars = (char *) malloc(original_str_length - num_elements_to_delete);

    for (i=0; i <= original_str_length; i++) {

        /*if char is not '-' or ' ' copy to new string*/
        if((s[i] != '-') && (s[i] != ' ')) {

            string_minus_chars[j] = s[i];
            j++;
        }
    }

    /*Print the string*/
    printf("String minus chars is %s\r\n", string_minus_chars);
    int string_minus_chars_length = strlen(string_minus_chars);

    printf("string_minus_chars_length %d\r\n", string_minus_chars_length);

    int extra_spaces = (string_minus_chars_length) / 3;

    printf("Number of spaces needed is %d\r\n", extra_spaces);

    /*allocate new string with spaces*/
    char* string_with_spaces = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*(extra_spaces + string_minus_chars_length));

    int space_counter = 0;
    int index = 0;

    for (i=0; i <= strlen(string_with_spaces); i++) {

         if(space_counter == 3) {
             printf("str2 index is %d, str1 index is %d,space counter is %d, inserting space\r\n",i, index, space_counter);
             string_with_spaces[i] = ' ';
             space_counter = 0;

         }
         else {
             printf("str2 index is %d,str1 index is %d,space counter is %d,  copying %c\r\n", i, index,space_counter, string_minus_chars[index]);
             string_with_spaces[i] = string_minus_chars[index];
         space_counter++;
         index++;
         }

      }

    printf("String_with_spaces is:%s\r\n", string_with_spaces);

    free(string_minus_chars);
    return string_with_spaces;

}


int main(void) {

    char s[12] = "ABC-3-26--54";
    char* string_returned;

    string_returned = FormatString(s);

    printf("String returned is %s",string_returned);
}
```

Comment: In the function, string_with_spaces contains the address given by malloc(). When returning into main(), this address is stored into string_returned. So you still have the possibility to free() it after the printf() call for example.

Comment: **1)** `for (i=0; i <= strlen(string_with_spaces); i++) {` You index beyond the size of the strings and **2)** `strlen(string_with_spaces)` not all your strings are nul-terminated.

Comment: **3)** `s[12] = "ABC-3-26--54";` 12 is too short here; you need one extra for the `'\0'` terminator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every allocated object has an owner responsible for freeing it. When you return such an object from a function, the caller becomes the owner. It is then the caller's responsibility to either free it or pass the ownership to some other function (or data).

In your case, `main` is the new owner of the string allocated in `FormatString`, so `main` should free it when it's done with.